# Cannot read property 'search' of undefined (Wikipedia API)

Tags: javascript, json, api, wikipedia

I'm messing around with the wikipedia API but I keep getting the error;

**"Cannot read property 'search' of undefined"**

Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong? When a user uses the search bar to try and find something, I'll use .map to go through the data and paste the data results into my resultDiv.

Here is my code; & an obligatory codepen. http://codepen.io/pixeluh/pen/wMdpbM?editors=101

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var searchBar = $("#search");
  var resultDiv = $(".results");
  var goButton = $("#go");

  $.ajax({
    url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?",
    data: {
      action: 'query',
      list: 'search',
      srsearch: searchBar.val(),
      format: 'json'
    }, //end of data
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data){
        var datatp = '';
        data.query.search.map(function(f) {
            datatp += f.title;
            datatp += f.snippet;
          }) //end of map
        resultDiv.html(datatp);
      } //end of success
  }); //end of ajax

}); //end of body func
```

```html
<html>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<container id="page">
  
  <div id="flex-container">
  <div class="search-bar">
    <form class="searchbar">
      <input type="search" name="wikisearch" placeholder="Search wiki..." id="search">
      <input type="submit" id="go" value="Go"/>
      
      <input type="button" id="random" value="Random" onclick="window.location ='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random';"/>
      
    </form>
   
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="results">
    <!-- search results go here-->
  </div>
  
</container>
</html>
```

Any help or guidance is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `data.query.search.map(function(f) {` data.query is undefined and you're trying to reference its search property.  Why undefined?  The data you got back doesn't look like you expect it does.  Look at the response you're getting from your ajax call (network tab in browser dev tools) and figure out what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling ajax on ready but it should be on submit like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var searchBar = $("#search");
  var resultDiv = $(".results");
  var goButton = $("#go");
  $('form').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?",
      data: {
        action: 'query',
        list: 'search',
        srsearch: searchBar.val(),
        format: 'json'
      }, //end of data
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(data){
          var datatp = '';
          data.query.search.map(function(f) {
              datatp += f.title;
              datatp += f.snippet;
            }) //end of map
          resultDiv.html(datatp);
        } //end of success
    }); //end of ajax
    return false;
  });
}); //end of body func
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bo17uuov/)**